# gpg-agent hangs after failed exit from password prompt

Tags: linux, gpg-agent

After trying to connect to an existing gpg-agent (with `keychain` for linux) and entering the password for it in the terminal with pinentry-curses, I for some reason failed to enter it correctly, and the password prompt got stuck (not sure if I entered the wrong password, or I hit ctrl-c, or what). Then the prompt froze, and the terminal window also started behaving weirdly, so I force killed the window. After this, opening a new terminal window would hang endlessly on connecting to the gpg-agent, before bringing up the password prompt, and in general it is impossible to connect to gpg-agent. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, pinentry-curses somehow becomes non-responsive and prevents gpg-agent from being used with it. As a workaround, pinentry-curses can be force killed, which will cause everything to work fine again. It's easy to find in top because it also uses near 100% cpu.

I am not sure what is really going wrong here and a better solution would be appreciated.